# javascript form validation- numerical values and passwords

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Hello I am trying to create a simple javascript password validation in order to submit a form. I just want users to be able to submit the form if they have the password correct. I understand this isn't a good way to do it but for the purposes of my project it will suffice. I have linked my form input data to a google form.

I also followed this tutorial if it helps:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/721795/Store-your-form-data-in-Google-Spreadsheet

The code I have works but I want to learn how I can modify it to make the form submit only if the password is correct and the no. of guest input is a numerical value. I also need it to not leave the page rather I envision a success or error notification that I can customize.

Here is my code.

the form html

```
<form>
  <input id="RSVPname" placeholder="NAME" type="text"><br>
  <input id="RSVPguests" placeholder="NO. OF GUESTS" type="text"><br>
  <input id="RSVPemail" placeholder="EMAIL" type="text"><br>
  <input id="RSVPpassword" placeholder="PASSWORD" type="text"><br>
</form>
<a id="ButtonSubmit" onclick="postContactToGoogle()" class="waves-effect waves-light waves-block btn-flat rsvpButton" type="submit" name="action"><span>rsvp</span></a>
```

the javascript

```
function postContactToGoogle() {
  var name = $('#RSVPname').val();
  var guests = $('#RSVPguests').val();
  var email = $('#RSVPemail').val();
  var password = $('#RSVPpassword').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1DdFHTm3Fg832ehplr89053TvF5osNzVrahmRnovCSw/formResponse",
    data: {
      "entry.2005620554": name,
      "entry.1498269582": guests,
      "entry.1045781291": email,
      "entry.788806858": password
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    statusCode: {
      0: function () {
        window.location.replace("ThankYou.html");
      },
      200: function () {
        window.location.replace("ThankYou.html");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I think the **statuscode** property has something to do with what I want.

Comment: Your function should return something.

Comment: So could I nest an if and else statement in a return statement?

Comment: where do you have the correct password or against what will you verify the entered password?

Comment: What about `<input id="RSVPguests" placeholder="NO. OF GUESTS" type="number"><br>` to make sure the number of guests is numerical?

Comment: @trincot the "password" is linked to my google form in a short-answer text input that requires the text "weddingtime!" In the google form itself, if a user inputs  "weddingtimeBLAH" then the form submits.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript form validation is about validation **before** the form submission. So it has nothing to do with http status codes, which come back from the server, so after submission.

But your postcontacttogoogle function just does nothing. It should preform checks, and depending on the result, 
submit the form (or not).

For example

```
if(name && name.length > 0 /*&& any other condition on your for data*/)  
{
  //invoke form submission
}
else 
{
   // alert("error");
   // or show inlined errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you are validating a password at any point.  You need to specify somewhere what the password is and then put in an `if`statement only to run the rest of the code if it is correct. Presumably you would put the entire ajax code inside, like this:

```
var correctPassword = 1234 // or whatever code you need to get your password
if (password == correctPassword && isNumeric(guests))
{  $.ajax({....
```

and then instead of `window.location.replace("ThankYou.html");` you can include your success or error notification.  `window.location.replace` will replace the entire window. You can use the `innerHTML` property to replace one particular div or `alert()` if you want a popup notification